# sh permission denied in exams2pdf

Tags: r, r-exams

I use R/exams to generate a PDF exam like this:

```
exams2pdf("swisscapital")
```

However, this results in the following error:

```
Loading required namespace: tinytex
sh: : Permission denied
```

Doing the same with `exams2html()` works well.

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: I cannot replicate this - at my end everything runs fine. Can you please add some more context: Is this caused by `latexmk()` from `tinytex`? Does `exams2pdf("swisscapital")` produce the same error? Does `exams2html()` work on your exercise? Does `latexmk()` work on other files? For the latter you could test: `utils::Sweave(system.file("Sweave", "Sweave-test-1.Rnw", package = "utils"))` to produce a .tex from the .Rnw and then `tinytex::latexmk("Sweave-test-1.tex")` to compile it to PDF.

Comment: The `exams2pdf("swisscapital")` returns same error. The `utils::Sweave(system.file...)` works well: appears the `.tex` file and can compile it with `tinytex::latexmk` (and appears a `.pdf`).

Comment: One more information: I've many `.Rnw` files and created one big `pdf` with `exams2pdf` (with `file=list.files(...` option). I rewrite `files=one.Rnw` and it doesn't work - and everything else too. I don't know what I did between them which causes the error. See my edit in the question.

Comment: If `exams2pdf("swisscapital")` produces the same error, please simplify your question accordingly. Then we don't have to deal with extra files, encodings, etc. And I presume `exams2html("swisscapital")` works? Or does it have the same error? What is the `traceback()` of the error? Does it still occur when you compile the PDF file in the current working directory: `exams2pdf("swisscapital", texdir = getwd())`?

Comment: @AchimZeileis see my update nr2. I hope this helps.

Comment: No, unfortunately, this is not how `traceback()` is used. Also, convoluting the question with so many unrelated details makes it really hard to drill down to the problem. So let's focus on `exams2pdf("swisscapital")` and try to resolve this. (1) After running `exams2pdf("swisscapital")` please run `traceback()` and post the output. (2) Please also try to `exams2pdf("swisscapital", dir = ".")`. Does this produce the same error or not? (3) Please report `getOption("pdfviewer")`. Maybe just the permission for the PDF viewer is missing?

Comment: Ah, the `pdfviewer` was the guilty (empty value). Please create an answer and I'll upvote and accept it. Thanks!

Comment: OK, good. I edited the question and removed all details that turned out to be unnecessary - in order to make it easier to find for others that have the same problem. For the same reason I also made my answer a bit more detailed than needed for you.

Comment: Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that this does not produce an "error" within R but only on the shell (sh), this is probably just a problem of displaying the PDF interactively at the very end. You can check whether

```
getOption("pdfviewer")
```

is correctly set to an application for viewing PDFs (e.g., `"/usr/bin/evince"`) and whether you have permission to use that application.

If there are problems with getting a proper PDF viewer called from within R, then simply use

```
exams2pdf("swisscapital", dir = ".")
```

which will write the PDF to your current working directory rather than displaying it in the PDF viewer. And then you can manually open the PDF outside of R.